# Python producer/consumer with exception handling

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, queue

I'm trying to write a seemingly simple implementation of the classic producer - consumer idiom
in Python. There is one comparably quick producer for multiple slower consumers. In principle, this
is easy to do using the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module, and the
library documentation has an example spawning only a few lines of code.

However, I also want the code to work properly in case exceptions occur. Both the producer
and all consumers should stop in case any of the following things happen:

- the producer fails with an exception
- any consumer fails with an exception
- the user stops the program (causing a KeyboardInterrupt)

After that, the whole process should fail raising the initial exception to inform the
caller about what went wrong.

The main challenge seems to be to cleanly terminate the consumer thread without ending up
in a blocking join(). It appears to be popular to set Thread.deamon=True, but to my
understanding this causes resource leaks in case the producer fails with an exception.

I managed to write an implementation that fulfills my requirements (see below). However
I find the code to be a lot more complex than expected.

Is there a leaner way to deal with these scenario?

Here are a couple of example calls and the resulting final log message from my current
implementation:

Produce and consume 10 items:

```
$ python procon.py
INFO:root:processed all items
```

Produce no items:

```
$ python procon.py --items 0
INFO:root:processed all items
```

Produce 5 items for 10 consumers, thus using only some of the available consumers:

```
$ python procon.py --items 5 --consumers 10
INFO:root:processed all items
```

Interrupt by pressing Control-C:

```
$ python procon.py
^CWARNING:root:interrupted by user
```

Fail to produce item 3:

```
$ python procon.py --producer-fails-at 3
ERROR:root:cannot produce item 3
```

Fail to consume item 3:

```
$ python procon.py --consumer-fails-at 3
ERROR:root:cannot consume item 3
```

Fail to consume the last item:

```
$ python procon.py --items 10 --consumer-fails-at 9
ERROR:root:cannot consume item 9
```

And here is the probably overly complex source code:

```
"""
Consumer/producer to test exception handling in threads. Both the producer
and the consumer can be made to fail deliberately when processing a certain
item using command line options.
"""
import logging
import optparse
import Queue
import threading
import time

_PRODUCTION_DELAY = 0.1
_CONSUMPTION_DELAY = 0.3

# Delay for ugly hacks and polling loops.
_HACK_DELAY = 0.05

class _Consumer(threading.Thread):
    """
    Thread to consume items from an item queue filled by a producer, which can
    be told to terminate in two ways:

    1. using `finish()`, which keeps processing the remaining items on the
       queue until it is empty
    2. using `cancel()`, which finishes consuming the current item and then
       terminates
    """
    def __init__(self, name, itemQueue, failedConsumers):
        super(_Consumer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._log = logging.getLogger(name)
        self._itemQueue = itemQueue
        self._failedConsumers = failedConsumers
        self.error = None
        self.itemToFailAt = None
        self._log.info(u"waiting for items to consume")
        self._isFinishing = False
        self._isCanceled = False

    def finish(self):
        self._isFinishing = True

    def cancel(self):
        self._isCanceled = True

    def consume(self, item):
        self._log.info(u"consume item %d", item)
        if item == self.itemToFailAt:
            raise ValueError("cannot consume item %d" % item)
        time.sleep(_CONSUMPTION_DELAY)

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not (self._isFinishing and self._itemQueue.empty()) \
                    and not self._isCanceled:
                # HACK: Use a timeout when getting the item from the queue
                # because between `empty()` and `get()` another consumer might
                # have removed it.
                try:
                    item = self._itemQueue.get(timeout=_HACK_DELAY)
                    self.consume(item)
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass
            if self._isCanceled:
                self._log.info(u"canceled")
            if self._isFinishing:
                self._log.info(u"finished")
        except Exception, error:
            self._log.error(u"cannot continue to consume: %s", error)
            self.error = error
            self._failedConsumers.put(self)


class Worker(object):
    """
    Controller for interaction between producer and consumers.
    """
    def __init__(self, itemsToProduceCount, itemProducerFailsAt,
            itemConsumerFailsAt, consumerCount):
        self._itemsToProduceCount = itemsToProduceCount
        self._itemProducerFailsAt = itemProducerFailsAt
        self._itemConsumerFailsAt = itemConsumerFailsAt
        self._consumerCount = consumerCount
        self._itemQueue = Queue.Queue()
        self._failedConsumers = Queue.Queue()
        self._log = logging.getLogger("producer")
        self._consumers = []

    def _possiblyRaiseConsumerError(self):
            if not self._failedConsumers.empty():
                failedConsumer = self._failedConsumers.get()
                self._log.info(u"handling failed %s", failedConsumer.name)
                raise failedConsumer.error

    def _cancelAllConsumers(self):
        self._log.info(u"canceling all consumers")
        for consumerToCancel in self._consumers:
            consumerToCancel.cancel()
        self._log.info(u"waiting for consumers to be canceled")
        for possiblyCanceledConsumer in self._consumers:
            # In this case, we ignore possible consumer errors because there
            # already is an error to report.
            possiblyCanceledConsumer.join(_HACK_DELAY)
            if possiblyCanceledConsumer.isAlive():
                self._consumers.append(possiblyCanceledConsumer)

    def work(self):
        """
        Launch consumer thread and produce items. In case any consumer or the
        producer raise an exception, fail by raising this exception  
        """
        self.consumers = []
        for consumerId in range(self._consumerCount):
            consumerToStart = _Consumer(u"consumer %d" % consumerId,
                self._itemQueue, self._failedConsumers)
            self._consumers.append(consumerToStart)
            consumerToStart.start()
            if self._itemConsumerFailsAt is not None:
                consumerToStart.itemToFailAt = self._itemConsumerFailsAt

        self._log = logging.getLogger("producer  ")
        self._log.info(u"producing %d items", self._itemsToProduceCount)

        for itemNumber in range(self._itemsToProduceCount):
            self._possiblyRaiseConsumerError()
            self._log.info(u"produce item %d", itemNumber)
            if itemNumber == self._itemProducerFailsAt:
                raise ValueError("ucannot produce item %d" % itemNumber)
            # Do the actual work.
            time.sleep(_PRODUCTION_DELAY)
            self._itemQueue.put(itemNumber)

        self._log.info(u"telling consumers to finish the remaining items")
        for consumerToFinish in self._consumers:
            consumerToFinish.finish()
        self._log.info(u"waiting for consumers to finish")
        for possiblyFinishedConsumer in self._consumers:
            self._possiblyRaiseConsumerError()
            possiblyFinishedConsumer.join(_HACK_DELAY)
            if possiblyFinishedConsumer.isAlive():
                self._consumers.append(possiblyFinishedConsumer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-c", "--consumer-fails-at", metavar="NUMBER",
        type="long", help="number of items at which consumer fails (default: %default)")
    parser.add_option("-i", "--items", metavar="NUMBER", type="long",
        help="number of items to produce (default: %default)", default=10)
    parser.add_option("-n", "--consumers", metavar="NUMBER", type="long",
        help="number of consumers (default: %default)", default=2)
    parser.add_option("-p", "--producer-fails-at", metavar="NUMBER",
        type="long", help="number of items at which producer fails (default: %default)")
    options, others = parser.parse_args()
    worker = Worker(options.items, options.producer_fails_at,
        options.consumer_fails_at, options.consumers)
    try:
        worker.work()
        logging.info(u"processed all items")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.warning(u"interrupted by user")
        worker._cancelAllConsumers()
    except Exception, error:
        logging.error(u"%s", error)
        worker._cancelAllConsumers()
```

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for, but there is a great python library called celery that you can use instead of writing your own queuing implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Celery looks interesting for complex tasks using web services and databases. For my particular task, the producer reads lines from a file and does some basic structural parsing and passes the data to the consumers - so mostly I/O intensive work. The consumers process the data doing CPU intensive work. As all this takes place in the memory on the same machine, Python's standard Queue seems to be fine for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answers so far gave good hints but lacked working code, I took the code from my question and wrapped it in a library, which is available from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/proconex/. You can find the source code at https://github.com/roskakori/proconex. While the interface feels sensible, the implementation still uses polling, so contributions are welcome.

Any exception in a producer or consumer thread is reraised in the main thread. Just make sure you use the `with` statement or `finally:worker.close()` to ensure all threads are shut down properly.

Here's a short example for a producer with two consumers for integer numbers:

```
import logging
import proconex

class IntegerProducer(proconex.Producer):
    def items(self):
        for item in xrange(10):
            logging.info('produce %d', item)
            yield item

class IntegerConsumer(proconex.Consumer):
    def consume(self, item):
        logging.info('consume %d with %s', item, self.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    producer = IntegerProducer()
    consumer1 = IntegerConsumer('consumer1')
    consumer2 = IntegerConsumer('consumer2')

    with proconex.Worker(producer, [consumer1, consumer2]) as worker:
        worker.work()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a queue with a cancel method that empties the internal queue, sets a cancelled flag, and then wakes everyone up.  The worker will wake up from join(), check the cancelled flag on the queue and act appropriately.  The consumers will wake up from get() and check the cancelled flag on the queue and print an error.  Then your consumer would just need to call the cancel() method in the event of an exception.

Unfortunately the Python Queue doesn't have a cancel method.  A few choices jump to mind:

- Roll your own queue (can be tricky to get it right)
- Extend the python queue and add the cancel method (couples your code to the internal implementation of the Python Queue class)
- Proxy the queue class and overload join/get with your busy wait logic (still a busy-wait hack, but confines it to one spot and cleans up the producer/consumer code)
- Find another queue implementation/library out there

Comment: Yes, moving the cancel logic to the queue certainly would clean up the worker code. Considering my requirements, the queue also would need to be able to remember possible exception information because I want the consumers to report the error to the worker, not just print it. But that certainly can be done. Does anyone know of an existing implementation of such a queue?