# Processing lots of data in python, should I use multiple threads/processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, data-processing

I am writing a program to process a huge file (~1.5GB). I am running Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 computer with a pretty good cpu (8 cores). Would it be more efficient in any way to use multiple threads or processes? As of now, it will take about an hour to process the whole thing. It goes at about 1000 data entries per second, with just over 4 million to process total.

Comment: Is there an easy way to start part-way through the file? (Depends on file structure) And does processing some parts of the file depend on other parts? If you can divide your input, and if each piece is independant, you could probably benefit by splitting it in up to (2 * cores) pieces.

Comment: if you are cpu bound, then maybe.

Comment: @HughBothwell each node is independent, but I can't start partway into the file, because I am loading it using pickle into a dictionary. I might try splitting it. Can you please explain why I would split it into 2 * cores (16) pieces, instead of just one for each core (8)?

Comment: @ethg242: because, on a given core, if one thread is delayed the other may be able to make use of the spare cycles. It's not guaranteed, only profiling will tell you what's best, but that's usually the maximum number of processes that make sense (depending on where your bottlenecks are).

Comment: At the very least you should have one (or more based on other comments) thread just reading and another thread processing your data.  Every time you call read() (or whatever method you use to read) the system is going to sleep a little under the hood (waiting for the disk) and you want to make sure you are using that time to do useful work (provided there is useful work to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [producer-consumer technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). There is a great explanation on this site: [Python producer/consumer with exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692834/python-producer-consumer-with-exception-handling)

The second example uses a library to implement it (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/proconex/) but don't! This is such a basic technique that it will be good for you to do it manually and tune to your needs.

In your case, the reader would be the producer, the processing would be done in several consumers.

If you need to consolidate the data in the end, write to another Queue and have another thread write/process it.

It it crucial that you [profile your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).

Comment: Another example that might be useful to you: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576999-concurrent-buffer-for-generators/

Comment: Would this be something like (Pseudocode) `for entry in file: new ProcessingThread(entry)`?

Comment: No, it is more like: q = Queue(); Producer(write_to=q); Consumer1(read_from=q); Consumer2(read_from=q); Please see the linked Wikipedia article. It has code samples.

Comment: I see, that's interesting. This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but I will mark this as accepted. Thanks!